# running windows Container in Kubernetes over AWS cloud

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, kubernetes, windows-container

I installed my existing Kubernetes Cluster (1.8) running in AWS using KOPS.

I would like to add Windows Container to the existing cluster but I can not find the right solution! :(

I thought of following these given steps given in:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/

I downloaded the node binaries and copied it to my Windows machine (Kubelet, Kube-dns, kube-proxy, kubectl) but I got a little confused about the multiple networking options.

They have also given the kubeadmin option to join the node to my Master, which I have no idea why since I used Kops to create my cluster.

Can someone advise or help me on how I can get my windows node added?

Comment: First, are you missing the [Prerequisites](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/windows/#prerequisites)? as per the doc, kube version should be 1.9

Comment: Have you had any success with this?

Comment: There is now preview support for Windows containers in EKS which might be an option. https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/tree/master/preview-programs/eks-windows-preview

Answer (score 1):

KOPS is really good if the default architecture satisfies your requirements, if you need to make some changes it will give you some trouble. For example I needed to add a GPU Node, I was able to add it, but unable to make this process automatic, being unable to create an auto scaling group.

Kops has a lot of pros, like creating all the cluster in a transparent way.

Do you really need a windows node?

If yes, try to launch a cluster using kube-adm, then joining the windows node to this cluster.

Kops will take some time to add this windows nodes feature.